# tensorflow federated takes long time to start training

Tags: tensorflow-federated

I'm facing a little bit annoying problem. The tensorflow-federated training (initialize and next) takes a long time to start (I'm not talking about time to finish, it's just starting time takes a while).

I doubt that this is due to either using: 1) with eager_mode():, 
or 2) use shuffling, as below:

```
with eager_mode():
    def preprocess(new_dataset):
        def map_fn(elem):
            return collections.OrderedDict([('x', tf.reshape(elem['In'], [-1])),('y', tf.reshape(elem['Out'],[1]))])

        DS2= new_dataset.map(map_fn)
        if Use_shuffle:
            return DS2.repeat(SNN_epoch).shuffle(shuffle_buffer).batch(SNN_batch_size)
        else:
            return DS2.repeat(SNN_epoch).batch(SNN_batch_size)
...
...
...
```

This is what I do:

```
trainer_Itr_Process = tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process(model_fn_Federated,server_optimizer_fn=(lambda : tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate=learn_rate)),client_weight_fn=None)
    FLstate = trainer_Itr_Process.initialize()
    # Track loss of different ...... of federated iteration
    for round_num in range(Fed_iter_min,Fed_iter_max): 
        FLstate, FLoutputs = trainer_Itr_Process.next(FLstate, federated_train_data)
......
......
......
```

This is the warning I'm getting:

```
W0616 11:30:00.217065 139843447875392 deprecation_wrapper.py:118] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_estimator/python/estimator/api/_v1/estimator/__init__.py:10: The name tf.estimator.inputs is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.estimator.inputs instead.

W0616 11:30:02.400945 139843447875392 deprecation_wrapper.py:118] From /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow_federated/python/core/impl/tensorflow_serialization.py:296: The name tf.initializers.variables is deprecated. Please use tf.compat.v1.initializers.variables instead.
```

Comment: Could the question be extend to point to which line takes a long time? Does "takes a long time to start" mean `trainer_Itr_Process.initialize()`, or `tff.learning.build_federated_averaging_process()`? If `next()` that maybe expected, since that is running the training of each client.

Comment: Following back up here--it is possible that you were using the old "reference executor", which was designed for ease of reasoning and not performance. Is this still an issue in newer releases of TFF?